# Rails 3.2 session_id never changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I have a backbone app running on top of my Rails app, which is making a number of AJAX requests. Oddly enough, the session ID cookie that my browser stores never seems to change. I can see the next request being made and the reply returning success. The response still hangs on to the old session ID, however, and thus I can't logout or change user state in any way.

Here's an example of the headers being sent:

Request to /login.json:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_session_id=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWY0YTI1Y2I5ZDE5MTgyYjJmN2MzMzZiMmE5ZWE2ZTAyBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTB1ZEozbzJCbUl4ZjluUDdCZVVEOXBhL0ZUeXNVRnFiMlFLblFTVUZPNGM9BjsARkkiDHVzZXJfaWQGOwBGaQg%3D--cf57849d4a4c0cbc5608574d959a772080b3afc5
Host:localhost:3000
If-None-Match:"7363e85fe9edee6f053a4b319588c086"
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5
X-CSRF-Token:0udJ3o2BmIxf9nP7BeUD9pa/FTysUFqb2QKnQSUFO4c=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Response from /login.json:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Date:Tue, 15 May 2012 22:44:46 GMT
Etag:"7363e85fe9edee6f053a4b319588c086"
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2011-07-09)
Set-Cookie:_session_id=BAh7B0kiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWY0YTI1Y2I5ZDE5MTgyYjJmN2MzMzZiMmE5ZWE2ZTAyBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTB1ZEozbzJCbUl4ZjluUDdCZVVEOXBhL0ZUeXNVRnFiMlFLblFTVUZPNGM9BjsARg%3D%3D--b16d1f8e4bba3c86d5e3e9ece1ae50f1ad898d00; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Request-Id:8e278bdd3504257bcb9956e068ca3ca3
X-Runtime:0.014739
X-Ua-Compatible:IE=Edge
```

Notice it's giving me a new session ID. Yet when I make my next request...

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_session_id=BAh7CEkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWY0YTI1Y2I5ZDE5MTgyYjJmN2MzMzZiMmE5ZWE2ZTAyBjsAVEkiEF9jc3JmX3Rva2VuBjsARkkiMTB1ZEozbzJCbUl4ZjluUDdCZVVEOXBhL0ZUeXNVRnFiMlFLblFTVUZPNGM9BjsARkkiDHVzZXJfaWQGOwBGaQg%3D--cf57849d4a4c0cbc5608574d959a772080b3afc5
Host:localhost:3000
If-None-Match:"53135bfd970c6b34f39ea3c4780ed240"
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5
X-CSRF-Token:0udJ3o2BmIxf9nP7BeUD9pa/FTysUFqb2QKnQSUFO4c=
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

The cookie has never changed.

Comment: If I call /logout.json directly, it works! This makes me think it's something to do with the request being generated by jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had an async. request firing at the same time, so the browser was never getting a chance to get the proper session ID.